# How to use validates_unique in Sequel validation_helpers plugin

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I am actually using Sequel plugin validation_helpers, and i did not have any problem using the validates_presence option. But when i try to use validates_unique it does not do anything.
I tried to put UNIQUE on my columns, but it raise an error and i just want an error in my sent message.
Here is what i did so far:

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  plugin :validation_helpers
  def validates
     super
     validates_presence[:username, :email]
     validates_unique(:username)
  end
end
```

So when i "forget" to put either a username or a mail it send an error Json object, but i can post as much user with the same username as i want.

So... Do someone can think about a solution?